# Can't access nested object property TS

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, serenity-platform

I'm trying to access the propertys of this object however my console is returning undefined..?

I've tried every work around, any suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You parse name of the property, but you should parse the whole property, so inside your loop use console.log(JSON.parse(targetItems[s]).CategoryId)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost certainly want

```
for (let s of targetItems)
```

instead of

```
for (let s in targetItems)
```

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed this. Any insight on why the first one works? Aren't they essentially the same?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#difference_between_for...of_and_for...in

Answer (score 2):

JSON.parse(targetItems[s]).CategoryId

Comment: Unfortuneately no, "targetItems[s])" gives a compile error of Argument of type object is not assignable to parameter of type string